# undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(int*, int)'

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gcc4, sles

I am trying to build C++ code using GCC 4.3.4 on SLES-15 and getting below error.

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /lib/libc.so.6:
(*IND*+0x0): multiple definition of __umoddi3
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /lib/libc.so.6:
(*IND*+0x0): multiple definition of __udivdi3
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: LicenseFile.o: in function `remove_dots(char const*)':

LicenseFile.cpp:(.text+0x16a8): undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(int*, int)'
```

I believe these both error a linked to same root cause, as same works on SLES-11 with GCC 4.3.4.

The default gcc version on SLES-15 is gcc 7 and I have installed gcc 4.3.4 and created softlink for g++-4.3.4 and gcc-4.3.4 as g++ and gcc respectively.

Below is the linker command

/usr/bin/g++ -m32 -pipe -O3 -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname -Wl,libmgutil.so.5.6.4 -Wl,--no-undefined  LicenseFile.o projectException.o projectResource.o projectServiceBase.o MessageStoreUtils.o OpenSSLInitializer.o ServiceConfigBase.o SmartHeapInit.o TimezoneManager.o Utils.o PriorityUtils.o stats_utils.o unix/projectService.o unix/projectLog.o unix/projectTrace.o unix/ServiceConfig.o    -L/home/build/builds/project/build/Linux-i686-SLES11/Release -L/home/build/builds/project/ivy-dist/Linux-i686-SLES11-Release/lib -L/home/build/builds/project/ivy-dist/Linux-i686-SLES11/lib -L/home/build/builds/project/ivy-dist/Linux-i686-SLES11-Release/lib -L/home/build/builds/project/ivy-dist/Linux-i686-SLES11/lib -L/home/build/builds/project/projectSDK/proto/Linux-i686-SLES11-opt/lib -L/home/build/builds/project/build/Linux-i686-SLES11-opt/license/4.0.0-nightly/lib -L/home/build/builds/project/Shared/C/licensing/build/Linux-i686-SLES11/Release -L/home/build/builds/project/project/proto/Linux-i686-SLES11-opt/lib  -Wl,--start-group -lCore -lssl -lcrypto -lmysqlclient -lboris -lapplic -llicense -lhermes -lpthread -lospace -ldl -Wl,--end-group -o /home/build/builds/project/build/Linux-i686-SLES11/Release/libmgutil.so.5.6.4

and the code from LicenseFile.cpp is (see the bold line where I believe it needs the _exchange_and_add() )

```
std::string td::string remove_dots(const char* host_id)
{
   std::string output;
   std::string str(host_id);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
       if (str[i] != ':') **output += str[i];**
   }
   return output;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `gcc` to compile C++ and link with libc and not (g++ and) libstdc++?

Comment: Does your version of the GCC libraries (libgcc/libstdc++ etc) match the version of your compiler? Does it work if you invoke the compiler explicitly as g++-4.3.4?

Comment: @frippe, No I am using g++-4.3.4 only to compile.

Comment: @nneonneo yes Iibgcc-4.3.4 and libstdc++-4.3.4 (we are using 32 bit) are also installed.
the code uses -m32 to compile.

Comment: Alright, then you should probably include more of the compiler and linker output as well as the commands and options you're using.

Comment: Needs a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you're mixing GCC < 5 with GCC >= 5 you might be running into std::string problems. It looks like `__exchange_and_add` is usually used as part of the old `std::string`.

Comment: @o11c I am not sure how its mixing "GCC < 5 with GCC >= 5"?. 
SLES-15 is a 64-bit OS with default GCC 7 and we are building the 32-bit code here using GCC 4.3.4.  Is it possible that this issue could be linking and mixing of 32 bit vs 64 bit code.

Comment: @o11c as the function definition is __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(int*, int)
so its sure for "+="

Comment: Compare results of **ld -V** on both OS.  
SLES-11 it gives below output:.  
GNU ld (GNU Binutils; SUSE Linux Enterprise 11) 2.20.0.20100122-0.7.9  
  Supported emulations:  elf_x86_64  
   elf_i386  
   i386linux  
   elf_l1om  
SLES-15 it has many emulation but missing **i386linux**. top few lines for sles-15  
GNU ld (GNU Binutils; SUSE Linux Enterprise 15) 2.35.1.20201123-7.18  
  Supported emulations:   
    elf_x86_64   
    elf32_x86_64   
    elf_i386   
    elf_iamcu   
     elf_l1om  
    elf_k1om  
     aarch64linux

Comment: @o11c so If its the issue of mixing GCC <5 and GCC >=5, then what is the solution?

Comment: @RakeshMehta stop using an ancient version of GCC?

Comment: @o11c moving to higher GCC required a lot of code change, so  its not feasible for the moment. 
On displaying the symbols for /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 it has _    __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(int volatile*, int)_
but not     **__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(int *, int)**